# Como trabalhar com scripts e folhas de estilo no Laravel 5.1

Tags: html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Sou novato em questão ao Laravel 5.1 (na verdade qualquer Laravel) e estou tendo muita dificuldade para entender de como trabalhar com folhas de estilo e scripts simples. Em diversos sites, eu vejo que preciso acrescentar um elemento no meu **composer.json** que é o `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"` mas em outros já encontrei dizendo que trabalhar dessa forma já está ultrapassado para a versão 5.1

Alguém tem um bom tutorial (em português) que me dê essa luz e que não saia do escopo inicial do laravel 5.1?

Comment: Você quer importar arquivos, é isso?

Comment: preciso saber como que eu faço coloco um arquivo  `assets\css\style.css` no meu **master.blade.php**, só isso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumindo:

```
public/css 
public/js
```

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/aqr.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/aqr.js') }}"></script>
```

ou:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/aqr.js'); }}

{{ HTML::style('css/aqr.css'); }}
```

Porém para usar a segunda opção é necessário instalar o Illuminate/HTML, segue o [link](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/install-illuminatehtml-laravel-5/).

Comment: mas segundo a documentação que eu li, todos os meus `assets` devem ficar dentro da pasta resouces... mesmo eu tendo eles ali ainda tenho que manter algo como uma versão de produção na pasta public?

Comment: https://blog.butecopensource.org/tutorial-laravel-5/
puts acabei de ler direito, ele fala pra usar na pasta public mas guardar alguma coisa na resources/assets

Comment: A melhor maneira **sempre** é a segunda opção. Mas quando se baixa o Laravel 5, a biblioteca `HTML` não vem junto. Tem que instalá-la a parte pelo **Composer**.

Answer (score 1):

Ajudando mais um pouco faça assim:

```
<link href="{!! asset('css/aqr.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/aqr.js') !!}"></script>
```

Dessa forma você estará usando a sintaxe nova para o blade em laravel 5.1, lembrando que a sintaxe antiga:

```
{{ }}
```

Está depreciada e logo será removida, então use sempre a nova:

```
{!! !!}
```

Comment: muito bom, obrigado, assim não vou precisar mexer nos meus arquivos **blade** tão cedo